# Strings appear exact, but they do not match?

Tags: php

I have two strings that I am comparing in a unit test. When I echo these strings, they look exactly the same...but...when comparing them with strcmp, they are not.

The one string is slightly, about 3 characters, longer than the other when looking at strlen().

I suspect that this could be because of line feeds/newlines.

The on string, $a is loaded from a file (on Windows), and the other $b is generated by the script. I'm comparing $b to $a in a unit test.

How do I go about converting all line feeds so that they are the same, regardless?

Comment: Not very likely, but it could also be encoding issues if it's an UTF-8 string.

Comment: Or unix v.s. windows line ending. `\n` v.s. `\r\n` would explain the length differences, assuming there's 3 line breaks in the input string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, find out if that's actually the problem. `var_dump` both strings in some environment where you'd see the blank lines if they're there.

Then, if line endings are the problem, remove them with `trim`

```
$str = trim($str);
```

Or `str_replace`

```
$str = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), "", $str);
```

Comment: The `str_replace()` method will also remove newlines in the middle of the string