# User inputted string, when containing certain special characters, does not match database string though they appear to be equivalent strings

Tags: php, ajax

I have searched for similar questions and have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961206/strings-appear-exact-but-they-do-not-match)
but it has not helped for my situation. On my site, a user inputs an answer. The string is sent via an ajax call to a php file. The string may or may not contain special characters, so I use

```
encodeURIComponent()
```

before the string is sent to the php file.

The user-inputted string is compared in the php file with a string that represents the "correct answer", and if the strings are found to be equivalent strings after processing, the user-inputted answer is "correct". I have not had a problem with any strings lately until today. Until today, strings with letters, special characters (parentheses, minus sign, plus sign) and numbers have worked fine using the following processing in php:

```
<?php include 'connect.php';

$UserInput = trim($_GET['userinput']);
$QID = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn, $_GET['qid']);
$sqlIQ = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($cxn, "SELECT answer FROM IndexQuestions WHERE sampqid = $QID"));


$StrReplaceArray = array("<i>", "</i>", "</sup>", " ");
$CorrectAnswer1 = str_replace($StrReplaceArray, "", $sqlIQ['answer']);
$CorrectAnswer2 = str_replace("<sup>", "^", $CorrectAnswer1);

$UserAnswer1 = str_replace(" ", "", $UserInput);
$UserAnswer2 = str_replace("+-", "-", $UserAnswer1);

if (strcasecmp($UserAnswer2, $CorrectAnswer2) == 0) {
    $CorrectOrNot = 'Correct';
} else {
    $CorrectOrNot = 'Incorrect';
}
```

However, the latest string is not working. The user-inputted string is **-2 ± √3** which is sent to the php file as **`-2 &plusmn; &radic;3`** (with or without the whitespace). The "correct answer" saved in another table is **`-2 &plusmn; &radic;3`**. I have echoed the following:

```
echo $UserAnswer2 . " " . $CorrectAnswer2; //after str_replace processing shown above
```

and the html output for each variable looks identical to me. I have also tried the following for comparative purposes (instead of `strcasecmp`):

```
if ($UserAnswer2 == htmlentities($CorrectAnswer2)) { //etc.
```

but still the same.

When I check a separate table (which stores the user's answer), the answer is stored the way I want it to be:

```
$unixtime = time();
$AnswerID = substr(md5(rand(0, 1000000)), 0, 10).$unixtime;

$sqlIQStats = mysqli_query($cxn, "INSERT INTO IQStats (answer_id, useranswer) VALUES ('$AnswerID', '".htmlentities($UserAnswer2)."')");
```

and appears in the database as **`-2 &plusmn; &radic;3`**.

The html charset the site uses is `charset=utf-8`.

var_dump gives the following (with no spaces for user answer): $UserInput and $UserAnswer2 both give string(8) "-2±√3" whereas $CorrectAnswer2 gives string(18) "-2±√3"

Does anyone have any ideas as to why the strings, after string-processing and comparison in the php file, are found to be inequivalent strings?

Comment: can you give us the var_dump?

Comment: OK....will need a minute

Comment: OK...I edited my post. I'm not sure how the user's inputted answer can be str(8) if it is saved in a separate table as -2 &plusmn; &radic;3

Answer (score 0):

OK...solved it by changing $UserInput to:

```
$UserInput = htmlentities(trim($_GET['userinput']));
```